# How can I prevent a Form_activated event from looping?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'd like the activated event to only run once. I've tried using an If condition but the Reload variable doesn't set to false and thus it keeps looping endlessly. Is there a way around this?

Form1.cs code:

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Class1.Reload == true) {
            Class1.Reload = false;
        }
    }
```

Class1.cs code:

```
 public class Class1 {
    public static void Refresh() { Reload = true; }
    public static bool Reload { get; set; }
```

Comment: This code does not loop. Please very specifically describe the actual behavior.

Comment: Also, is this web, winforms what?

Comment: sometimes we use the `Tag` property for this.. `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(castToWhatever)sender).Tag)) return;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unsubscribe from the event the first time it is triggered.

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Activated -= Form1_Activated;
    // Do other stuff here. 
}
```

Comment: doesn't work either. Keeps looping. It doesnt apply the removal of the event.

Comment: The only way it would keep looping is if you keep subscribing to it. How are you subscribing to the event?

Comment: Nevermind your solution does indeed work. Great job!

Comment: If someone down votes the answer they should specify why!!

Answer (score 1):

While CathalMF's solution is valid, I'll post the solution I implemented, whose aim was to **refresh a DatagridView when I come back to the main form**.

```
 private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Class1.Reload == true) {
            Activated -= Form1_Activated;
            Class1.Reload = false;
            //Here I implement the code to refresh a DatagridView
            Activated += Form1_Activated;
        }
    }
```

Class1.cs stays the same.